# Search box or auto complete box on stack site list in footer

Tags: feature-request, footer

I wanted to access https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ but did not know the url. So naturally I came back to stackoverflow.com and browsed to the big list of stack exchange sites in the footer.

Then I was stuck because I did not find raspberrypi and I overlooked that more(14) link.

Therefore, I switched to meta and a search brought me to https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#name and there I found the link.

But given the ever increasing amount of new stack exchange sites it would be much nicer to have a search box to find and open a stack exchange site by just typing some words.

Comment: You mean [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hmggd.png)?

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/sites <-- where _all_ sites are listed. Beta sites are not in the footer.

Comment: @Antony this is available only on Meta for now but yeah, once deployed over the network this feature request can be marked [meta-tag:status-completed]. :)

Comment: @Antony yes I mean this. But I would look to the footer. The sites are very prominent at the footer and I remember to look there.